# como lleno un combobox con una tabla en sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans-8.2

quisiera saber como llenar un combo Box con una tabla que tengo en SQLITE, ya que he buscando TUTORIALES pero están con MYSQL y no comprendo así, ya he traido datos hacia un jtable, pero no se como hacer para traer a un combobox, algaun borrador que me proporcionen me serviría para entender como lo hago.

```
public class conexion {
String strConexionDB="jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Mercadeo Eforsalud/Documents/Desktop/biblioteca.s3db";
Connection conn = null;
public conexion(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(strConexionDB);
        System.out.println("conexion establecida");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error de conexion"+ e);
    }

}


public int ejecutarSentenciaSQL(String strSentenciaSQL){
    ResultSet res = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(strSentenciaSQL);
        res = pstm.executeQuery();
        return 1;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

}
ESTO ES LO QUE HE HECHO PERA PARA CONECTARME A LA BD

Comment: La base es exactamente igual para cualquier base de datos. Tu problema es como conectarte a una base sqlite? entonces esa deberia ser tu pregunta no. En tal caso, que error tenes al tratar de conectarte?

Comment: ya estoy conectado, lo que quiero es llenar un combobox con una tabla que tengo en la bd de sqlite

Comment: Si estas conectado, el resto es exactamente igual... sqlite es una base con algunas cosas restringidas, pero en general todo funciona exactamente igual.. que problemas particulares tuviste? no puedo no nos ayuda a saber cual es tu problema...

Comment: el codigo de arriba es la conexion a la bd pero no tengo idea de que coloco para llenar un combobox con una tabla que tengo en la bd de sqlite

Comment: Sigo sin entender tu problema.. sabes llenar un combo de otra forma? no sabes hacer un query? ese metodo no devuelve algo que puedas mandar a un combo, Entiendo que tenes un problema, mas que un problema, tenes desconocimiento, pero no entiendo hasta donde llega el mismo, porque si no sabes hacer un query, es mucho lo que hay que explicarte.... sabes hacerlo en mysql?

Comment: no, es desconocimiento, es que apenas estoy estudiando y estoy varado en esto, un ejemplo seria bueno ya que he visto con mysql pero lo hacen como distinto o no comprendo bien

Comment: es que es exactamente igual. Mysql es una base de datos, sqlite es otra base de datos.. pero si te conectaste a la base de datos, deberia funcionar exactamente igual. Pone el codigo que usas contra mysql y veamos si hay que corregir algo...

Comment: esque solo he visto sqlite, lo que trato de explicar es que no se como comenzar para llenar un combobox con la info que tengo en la tabla de la bd, osea yo ya llene un jtable con info de la base de datos, ahora quiero saber como lleno un combobox

Comment: Ok.. entonces, esa es tu pregunta, y el codigo que mostras tiene que reflejar eso.. que sabes abrir una db.. que sabes traer los datos.. y si llenaste una tabla, un combo es igual!!!! pero bueno.. aclara todo eso en la pregunta... si no, no se entiende cual es el problema que tenes...